# How to read mime multipart messages in javamail

Tags: jakarta-mail, mime, multipart

How to read mime multipart messages in javamail?

I want to display the message in webview.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Start with [this JavaMail FAQ entry](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#readattach).

See also the msgshow.java demo program included with JavaMail.